# Denoting covers from a set $X$

Tags: general-topology

How would one denote generated sets from a given cover within a set $X$ utilizing the definition in $(1.1)$

$$(1.1)$$
A cover of a set $X$ is a collection of sets whose union contains $X$ as a subset. Rigorously speaking we have if:

$$C = \Big\{U_{a} : a \in A \Big\}$$

is an indexed family of sets $U_{a}$, then is cover of $X$ if

$$X \subset \cup  \, \,  U_{a}$$

Comment: "How would one denoted generated sets from a given cover within a set $X$" I don't understand the actual question. Could you give an example of what exactly is unclear? The definition itself? Or some element of the notation?

Comment: What I initially didn't understand was the notion of an "indexed set"

Comment: any set is an "indexed set" if you want it to be. $\mathbb{R}=\{ x_r: r \in \mathbb{R}\}$ ( where $x_r=r$) as a boring example. In this case the indexed set is just a fancy way to write the identity. There is no mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you've taken this definition from the Wikipedia page for a Cover : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_(topology)

Note that in that definition $A$ is implicitly defined to be an indexing set. Wikipedia doesn't mention this, and it seems to be what is causing your confusion here.

Therefore we have $U_a \subseteq X$ for all $a \in A$, and the union of all such $U_a$ to be a superset of $X$ (hence the notion of *covering*), i.e.

$$X \subseteq \bigcup_{a \in A} U_a$$

Comment: $U_a \subseteq X$ need not be true, if $X$ is a subset of some space $Y$.

Comment: Interesting can the definition of a cover be used to prove a set is a subset of a compact set within a Topological Space $X$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The "indexed family" bit is mere notational convenience, for use in proofs.

Suppose we have a set $X$.

Then a cover of $X$ is a subset $\mathcal{C} \subseteq \mathscr{P}(X)$ (the power set of $X$, so all $C \in \mathcal{C}$ are subsets of $X$), such that:

$$\bigcup \mathcal{C} = X$$

Which means that

$$\forall x \in X: \exists C \in \mathcal{C}: x \in C$$

And if $Y \subseteq X$ a cover of $Y$ (in $X$) is such a $\mathcal{C} \subseteq \mathscr{P}(X)$ such that $$Y \subseteq \bigcup \mathcal{C}$$